# Installer for Jitsi SIP Communicator

Tags: java, sip, jitsi

I have to create installer for Jitsi SIP Communicator after I have done changes in it. I have searched on net and found some steps as given below:

1. SOFTWARE REQUIREMENTS

   - Cygwin:
     include libs "make, gcc & g++"
     http://cygwin.com/setup.exe
   - MinGW:
     (only gcc, no g++) (use installation file .zip, taken into account that build.xml is looking for a sub-folder x86 y
     x64 into MinGW root folder)
     http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download
     Install in C:\MinGW\x86
   - copy mingw-make.exe to make.exe (folder C:\MinGW\x86{-}\bin)
   - bzip2:
     (v1.0.5 in this case): install in C:\MinGW\bzip2
     http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/bzip2.php
   - xz:
     (v5.0.3 in this case): unzip in C:\MinGW\xz
     http://tukaani.org/xz/xz5.0.3windows.zip
   - make for win32:
     (v3.8.1 in this case)
     http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/make.php
   - wix35-binaries:
     (v3.5 in this case): unzip in C:\Program Files\WiX
   - Use binaries (wix35-binaries.zip), not WiX .msi installer.
     http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/60102#DownloadId=204418
   - ant:
     (v1.8.3 in this case): unzip in C:\apache-ant-1.8.3
     http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
   - jdk1.6:
     (v1.6.0_31 in this case)
2. ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:

   - Export variables containing:
   - ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.8.3
   - JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31
   - Add to PATH :
     %ANT_HOME%\bin
     C:\MinGW\bin
     C:\cygwin\bin
     C:\MinGW\msys\1.0
     C:\Program Files\WiX
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnuwin32\Make\bin
3. ADDITIONAL TASKS:

   - Edit "installers.properties" adding path for JRE files to add into installer and/or for JRE (.zip or folder) files.
   - Compile project.
4. EXECUTE build SCRIPT:

   - Launch Cygwin terminal
   - Go to /cygdrive/.../{dir_root Jitsi}
     -Execute:
     ant build-installation-wix (to create an installer for windows x86)
     ant build-installation-wix-64 (to create an installer for windows x64)
     ant build-installation-linux (to create an installer for linux)
     ant dmg (to create an installer for MacOSX, only run on MacOSX

But when I excute commands given above on cygwin I found the following error:

> build-installation-wix-base:
>   [propertyfile] Creating new property file: D:\javaprojects\jitsi\release\windows\versionupdate.properties
>       [mkdir] Created dir: D:\javaprojects\jitsi\release\windows\tmp\light
>        [exec] Makefile:40: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   D:\javaprojects\jitsi\resources\install\build.xml:302: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\javaprojects\jitsi\resources\install\build.xml:403: exec returned: 2

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issues as you mentioned. I finally tried myself, and built Jitsi in Windows, both 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

### I didn't use Cygwin, but just used Mingw+Msys.

Here is what I did:

1. Install Mingw + Msys in C:/mingw/x86 folder
2. Install ANT
3. Install BZip2 in c:/mingw/bzip2
4. Install xz in c:/mingw/xz
5. Install Wix , I installed in C:/win35. Change the location of wix installation path in resources/install/build.xml
   6) Delete the make.exe file inside mingw/msys/1.0/bin and rename the mingw/bin/mingw-make.exe to make.exe

### I had to change the Makefiles a little, here are the changes I made:

1) Removed quotes in Target directory initialization:

```
-    target.dir := "$(TARGET_DIR)"
-    cygwin.target.dir := "$(TARGET_DIR)"
+    target.dir := $(TARGET_DIR)
+    cygwin.target.dir := $(TARGET_DIR)
```

2) Changed single line echo into multiline:

```
-       echo.exe -e '#define PRODUCTNAME "$(PRODUCTNAME)"\n#define PRODUCTBUILDVERSION "$(PRODUCTBUILDVERSION)"\n#define
+       echo #define PRODUCTNAME "$(PRODUCTNAME)" > $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h
+       echo #define PRODUCTBUILDVERSION "$(PRODUCTBUILDVERSION)" >> $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h
+       echo #define TARGET_BASENAME "$(TARGET_BASENAME)" >> $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h
+       echo #define TARGET_BASENAME_EXE "$(TARGET_BASENAME).exe" >> $(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h
```

3) In the resources/install/installers/properties - Specified the location where IzPack is installed, and gave location for zip files of JRE. When I used the setup file of JRE, the build didn't bundle the JRE along"

```
+windows.jre.zip=C:\\JavaInstallers\\jre32.zip
+windows.jre64.zip=C:\\JavaInstallers\\jre64.zip
```

### Finally, I wrote a simple batch script to build the installer:

```
set PATH=C:\apps\apache-ant-1.9.1\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\wix35

set ANT_HOME=C:\apps\apache-ant-1.9.1
set JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
set BZ2_HOME=c:/mingw/bzip2_x86
set LZMA_HOME=C:/mingw/xz
set MINGW_HOME=C:/mingw

start /B /LOW /WAIT ant build-installation-wix
```

---

This is for the 32 bit version.

For 64 bit though, I had to build bzip2 from source myself. That can be done by downloading Bzip2 source and compile it through mingw. Was an easy task. Rest of the steps are all the same.

Please try this out and let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: These are the best instructions I was able to find anywhere.  Got me closer than anything else I was able to find.  Still having some issues with running the executable but at least I got it to compile.

Comment: @Paramesh: Even after following these steps, I'm getting following error: `run.h:23:43: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory`