# Jitsi Installer Missing .dlls

Tags: java, c++, dll, jitsi

I have been trying to re-build the Jitsi Source to a WIN X86 .exe which has been working perfectly fine for me but i am facing the issue of when i go to run the installer on any PC it is saying to me [image]

if i place the dll with the installer in the same folder not complied into it it will install fine with no issues or errors.

I am no Java Expert pretty novice i was just changing some colors of windows.

I am hoping either someone can tell me how to compile it into the installer or change something to make it work and not give me this error.
this isnt the only .Dll it is missing the ones that are missing are

- libbz2-2.dll
- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
- liblzma-5.dll

Comment: How do you build your installer? Is it written in Java or C++? Does it really uses Windows Installer, a file with .msi extension?

Comment: sorry it builds an installer using Java i think, has a build.xml file which is used to create all the Jars then with the same file it can build the installer, the installer it builds is an .EXE for x86 but im pretty sure i can create an .msi

Comment: The fact that `build.xml` for building says that Apache Ant is used to build the product. Of course Ant is run by Java, yet you can build native executables with Ant. So you should change linker options in your build options somewhere in `build.xml` so that the .EXE is built with *statically linked* libraries rather than *dynamic* ones.

Answer (score 0):

By default you must have these libraries in your Windows's System32 folder. In Java applications you can use the `-Djava.library.path` parameter to load DLLs from different places. For example:

```
java.exe -Djava.library.path="c:\\dlls" something.jar
```

to make the JVM load DLLs from the c:\dlls folder.

Comment: Putting application DLLs into system directories is frowned upon for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

Your installer depends on these DLLs and they must be in the current directory with the installer .exe.

Usually installers do not need additional DLLs, you could recompile your installer so that it *statically* links to the required libraries, including C/C++ runtime libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer, [Installer for Jitsi SIP Communicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495465/installer-for-jitsi-sip-communicator/22658530#22658530) and modify the bat file with below content:

```
set JAVA_HOME=<Your Java Home>
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;<ApacheBinPath>;c:\mingw\bin;c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10

set ANT_HOME=<Ant Home>
set BZ2_HOME=altel\src\native\windows\setup
set LZMA_HOME=c:\mingw\xz
set MINGW_HOME=c:\mingw
start /B /LOW /WAIT ant build-installation-wix
```

It worked for me

Comment: Recommend expanding to explain why and how this helps.