# Error in creating Jitsi windows Installer following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495465/installer-for-jitsi-sip-communicator/22658530#22658530

Tags: jitsi

I am trying to make Jitsi installer, following 
[Installer for Jitsi SIP Communicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495465/installer-for-jitsi-sip-communicator/22658530#22658530)

but facing following error

```
wix-sign-file:
     [exec] setup.msi: 52.3 MiB / 199.0 MiB = 0.263, 1.2 MiB/s, 2:44
     [exec] process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm.exe -f ../../../../resources/install/windows/config.h, ...) failed.rm.exe -f ../../../../resources/install/windows/config.h
     [exec]
     [exec] make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.Makefile:69: recipe for target 'E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/config.h' failed
     [exec]
     [exec] echo #define PRODUCTNAME "Jitsi" > E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/config.hmake.exe: [E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/config.h] Error 2 (ignored)
     [exec]
     [exec] echo #undef PACKAGECODE >> E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/config.h
     [exec] echo #undef PACKAGESIZE >> E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/config.h
     [exec] echo #define PRODUCTBUILDVERSION "1.1.0.9" >> E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/config.h
     [exec] C:/mingw/bin/windres.exe -I../../../../resources/install/windows -IE:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp setup.rc -O coff -o E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/setup.res
     [exec] 'C:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     [exec] operable program or batch file.
     [exec] 'C:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     [exec] operable program or batch file.
     [exec] C:/mingw/bin/gcc.exe -O2 -Wall -Wreturn-type -DWINVER=0x0502 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0502 -IE:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp -DBSPATCH_API_STATIC -DBZ2_API_STATIC -I. -IC:\MinGW\bzip2/include -IC:\MinGW\bzip2 -DLZMA_API_STATIC -IC:\MinGW\xz/include -IC:\MinGW\xz/api -I../run bspatch.c lasterror.c nls.c ../run/registry.c setup.c E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode
\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/setup.res -mwindows -LC:\MinGW\bzip2/lib/ -LC:\MinGW\bzip2 -LC:\MinGW\xz/lib/ -LC:\MinGW\xz/.libs -o E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/setup.exe -ladvapi32 -lbz2 -llzma -lole32 -lshell32
     [exec] Makefile:63: recipe for target 'E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/setup.exe' failed
     [exec] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llzma
     [exec] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
     [exec] make.exe: *** [E:\JZ\Code\JavaCode\jitsilatest\LANJr4D-jitsi-b56f30acd2d1/release/windows/tmp/setup.exe] Error 1

BUILD FAILED
```

Although i have xz package in C:/MingW/xz and also set the environment variable for it LZMA_HOME

Thanks

JZ

Answer (score 0):

For this error you have to have `/src/native/windows/setup` in your PATH.  Then copy either `/src/native/windows/setup/lib/x64/libbz2.a` or `/src/native/windows/setup/lib/x86/libbz2.a` and `libllzma.a` files into `/src/native/windows/setup/lib`.  Remove all other path and system variable references to bzip2 and lzma.  You do not need xz or bzip2 anymore since the files are included at the above location and the xz.exe executable is included at `/resources/install/windows`.  If you use the external bzip2 like all the internet instructions say, you will get bzip2.dll errors when you finally do manage to make the installer and try run the executable.

All the instructions on the internet are obsolete/wrong.  All of them.  Every single one!  NOBODY has bothered to point this out anywhere.  NOBODY.  You will not even find any info in the dev or user mail lists.  Only little breadcrumbs of current info here and there.  I had to figure this little gem out on my own.  Took me several days.  Fun times.

This isn't the only wrong thing in all the instructions.  I am still working through them all.  Once I get a perfect install I'll try add updated instructions somewhere.

I can get it to compile but the executable will crash.  If I use 64bit Java on the 32bit executable then I can get it to run.  So there is still something wrong with the C wrapper.  No information anywhere.  Everyone who has posted the same problem has not had any response and are all in the same boat.